# How are distances scaled in ggplot2::position_stack?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I want to plot a population pyramid with labels next to the stacked bars of a ggplot. I use `position_stack(vjust=1.3)` to get the labels to appear next to the 'top' of the bars using the code below, but I do not understand how the command scales the position of the labels.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(
  sex = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), 
  ag = c("0-9", "10-19", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70+"), 
  n = c(-0.21, -0.12, -0.09, -0.03, -0.04, -0.01, 0, 0, 0.22, 0.11, 0.06, 0.04, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0),
  stringsAsFactors = F
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=ag, y = n, fill=sex)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_brewer("",labels = c("Women", "Men"), palette = "Set1") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(data = . %>% dplyr::filter(sex == "M"),
            aes(label = n),
            position=position_stack(vjust=1.3)) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% dplyr::filter(sex == "F"),
            aes(label = n),
            position=position_stack(vjust=-0.3))
```

In the resulting plot, the labels are not equidistant from the upper-edge of the bars. I want the labels to appear neatly next each bar. [image]

Comment: Seems like you might want `nudge_y` (because of coordinate flipping) instead of `position_stack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `position_nudge`

```
   df %>% 
{ggplot(data=.,aes(x=ag, y = n, fill=sex,label = n)) +
  geom_col() +  
  geom_text(position = position_nudge(y = ifelse(.$sex == "F", -0.02, 0.02)))+
  coord_flip()}
```

[image]